# Doubt in B92 quantum cryptography protocol

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, polarization, quantum-optics

I am reading an article on B92 protocol which uses heralded SPDC photons. I don't understand a part of the paragraph. This paragraph mentions Bob's experimental setup for receiving the photons.

> In Bob’s part of the experimental archi-
> tecture, a 50:50 beam splitter (BS)
> is placed in the path of the incoming photons, where each
> photon has 50% probability to go to the transmitted arm and
> 50% to go to the reflected arm. In the transmitted arm of the
> BS, one polarizing beam splitter (PBS2) is placed and a fibre
> coupler (FC2) collects any photon that transmits through the
> PBS and sends it to a single photon detector (SPAD2). So, in
> that arm only D polarized photons have 50% probability to
> get detected while V polarized photons have 0% probability.
> In the reflected arm of the BS, a similar combination of PBS
> (PBS1) and fibre coupler (FC1) is placed with an additional
> half-waveplate (HWP) just behind the PBS. This HWP con-
> verts D photons to V photons and vice versa. So, only V
> photons sent by Alice pass through the PBS and get detected
> in this arm half the number of times, but no D polarized
> photon is detected.

Here is the image for better understanding

[image]

I understand that in the transmitted arm, if a photon is D polarised, it gets polarised to H and V when passes through PBS2 and Bob knows that the photon is D polarised when he detects H photon in that arm. This way only D polarised photons are detected in that arm.

What I don't understand is in the reflected arm, the HWP converts D photons to V photons and vice versa. So if D photon is passed through PBS1(originally V), there is 50% probability that V photon is detected. If V photon is passed through the PBS1(originally D), V photon will be detected with 100% probability. So how does Bob differentiate between D and V photon in the reflected arm? I get that only V photons will be detected in that arm but if D photon passes through the BS, won't it falsely detect D photon as V photon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the terms.

I would like to change the nomenclature to s- and p- polarized light, I will keep the D for diagonally polarized. Light with s-polarization (equivalent to your V, for vertical) is reflected by the PBS, p-polarization (H, horizontal) is transmitted.

If the signal has a mix of s- and D- polarized photons, then the half-wave plate will swap them around, s- photons become D and vice versa. The PBS allows only p-polarization through, this means that impinging D polarization will pass 50%, while s-polarized photons will be blocked. That's it! In the reflection arm, the ones being detected are the original V (s-polarized) photons! The sequence is as follows: s-polarized-> HWP: go to D-> PBS: 50% chance of transmission. The other photons from Alice, D polarized -> HWP: go to s-pol. -> PBS: 100% reflection.

In the above quote, the phrase

> So, only V photons sent by Alice pass through the PBS and get detected in this arm half the number of times, but no D polarized photon is detected.

Refers to the original polarization (note that it says "V-photons sent by Alice"), not the one after the HWP.

In other words, this statement from your question:

> If V photon is passed through the PBS1(originally D), V photon will be detected with 100% probability.

Is wrong, the V (s-polarized) photons are reflected, not transmitted.

Comment: I used to think that PBS converts the D polarized photons to s and p polarisation with equal intensity. Is that incorrect?

Comment: No, that is correct. But if we talk about single, diagonally polarized photons, then there's only 50% chance that it gets transmitted. It will get either transmitted or reflected, not split into 2 intensities.